# Can not see list of objects in Struts 2?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

This is my JSP file where I am able to insert data in to database properly, but I am       unable to get a list of objects I have inserted in the database.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>

<html>

  <table border="1px" cellpadding="8px" >
    <tr>    
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>DepartmentID</th>
        <th>Department Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Delete</th>

    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="employeeList" var="emp">
        <tr>    
            <td><s:property value="firstName" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="lastName" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="phoneNumber" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="departmentId" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="departmentName" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="salary" /></td>
            <td><a href="delete?id=<s:property value="id"/>">delete</a>       
          </td> 
              </tr>
    </s:iterator>
  </table>
  <br />

</body>
</html>
```

This is my Action Class

```
enter code here
package com.indus.training.action;

 import java.util.List;

 import com.indus.training.model.Employee;
  import com.indus.training.service.EmployeeService;
 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

  public class EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 316991296006785831L;

private Integer id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String departmentName;
private Integer departmentId;
private Integer salary;
private String phoneNumber;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getDepartmentName() {
    return departmentName;
}

public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}

public Integer getDepartmentId() {
    return departmentId;
}

public void setDepartmentId(Integer departmentId) {
    this.departmentId = departmentId;
}

public Integer getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

Employee emp = new Employee();
EmployeeService empSvc = new EmployeeService();

public String execute() {
    this.employeeList = empSvc.getEmployeeList();
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String add() {

    empSvc.saveEmployee(getEmp());
    this.employeeList = empSvc.getEmployeeList();
    return SUCCESS;

}

public Employee getEmp() {
    return emp;
}

public void setEmp(Employee emp) {
    this.emp = emp;
}

public EmployeeService getEmpSvc() {
    return empSvc;
}

public void setEmpSvc(EmployeeService empSvc) {
    this.empSvc = empSvc;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

List<Employee> employeeList;
public String delete (){
    empSvc.deleteEmployee(getId());
    return SUCCESS;

}



public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
    return employeeList;
}

public void setEmployeeList(List<Employee> employeeList) {
    this.employeeList = employeeList;
}

     }
```

this is my struts.xml file

```
enter code here
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

 <struts>

<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<!-- Add your package and namespace here -->
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">


    <!--Add your actions here -->
    <action name="welCome" class="com.indus.training.action.EmployeeAction">
        <result name="success">/WelCome.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="deleteAction" class="com.indus.training.action.EmployeeAction"
        method="delete">
        <result name="success">/Home.jsp</result>

    </action>

    <action name="saveDetails" class="com.indus.training.action.EmployeeAction"
        method="add">
        <result name="success">/Home.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/Home.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <!-- <action name="welCome" class="com.indus.training.action.WelCome"> 
        <result name="success">/WelCome.jsp</result> </action> -->


    <!-- Actions end -->

</package>
    </struts>
```

Comment: I'll take a stab in the dark and say however you're initializing the `employeeList` action property doesn't work. Of course, it's impossible to know, because all I can see is your JSP. Which should be trimmed to include only the relevant code.

Comment: While unlikely to cause your problem, your HTML code is majorly malformed. Hopefully, that is due to copying and pasting the code in your question and not how it actually is in your project. Otherwise, you might want to take a few minutes to read over all of your code and provide some basic formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these mappings that should redirect to the action as a result which returns a list of objects from the service layer.

```
<action name="saveDetails" class="com.indus.training.action.EmployeeAction" method="add">
  <result type="redirectAction">welCome</result>
  <result name="input">/Home.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="deleteAction" class="com.indus.training.action.EmployeeAction" method="delete">
  <result type="redirectAction">welCome</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Actually I am not able to view Home page with this configuration